# Using iOS push notifications to initiate a download when app is in state "not running"

Tags: ios, background, push

The documentation at https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/BackgroundExecution/BackgroundExecution.html (Section "Using push notifications to initiate a download") states: "For a push notification to trigger a download operation, the notification’s payload must include the content-available key with its value set to 1. When that key is present, the system wakes the app in the background (or launches it into the background) and calls the app delegate’s application:didReceiveRemoteNotification:fetchCompletionHandler: [...]"

Does "or launches it into the background" mean that the app will be started if it's in the state "not running"? According to my tests this is not the case, such push messages are ignored if the app is in the state "not running".

Comment: How did you terminate the app for your testing?  The app won’t be relaunched if the app was terminated by swiping up. See https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiapplicationdelegate/1623013-application

Comment: @Paulw11 I terminated it by pressing the "stop" button in Xcode while it was running via debugger. As far as I know this should have the same effect as when the app gets killed by the system due to memory shortage. I've also tried restarting the device because of "the user must relaunch your app or restart the device before the system attempts to launch your app automatically again" but the app did not get launched in the background. Does it work for you?